# When listing dependencies in a conda env file, does order matter?

Tags: python, conda, python-packaging

I have a conda env file with long list of dependencies. I was considering sorting them alphabetically for readability.

But then I wondered: would changing the order break things?

Sounds like it shouldn't, given this GitHub issue: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/4957

More generally, if there's a best practice for how to order conda env dependencies, I'm interested in learning. Thank you.

Addendum (23/3/2022): the output of `conda env export` is sorted alphabetically, so i'm guessing it's fine?

Comment: If it were me, and if I didn't find any additional information, I think what I would do is create a few new environments using say the requirements order you have now and the sorted requirements.  I would capture the output while building each environment.  Then I would compare the output and/or compare the two environments themselves to see what, if any, differences there are between them.  (I'm not a Conda user, but I assume that the concept of virtual environments applies equally there)

Comment: I wasn't able to find an answer but I encountered this in projects. Sometimes, putting a big library (that has many dependencies) on top of the list, solves some issues.